# Can AngularJS directive pre-link and post-link functions be customized?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have seen many references to AngularJS **pre- and post-link functions** in literature about AngularJS.

I am not sure however whether these can be customized or are internal to the framework.

In other words, as an AngularJS developper, can I provide my own **pre and post link functions** to my custom directives?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes you can, as per @Mikke's answer. To sum up, there are four ways to declare linking functions:

1. From within `compile` specifying both `preLink` and `postLink` functions explicitly:

   ```
   compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
     return {
       pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... },
       post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
     }
   }
   ```
2. From within `compile` returning only `postLink` implicitly:

   ```
   compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
     return function postLink( ... ) { ... }
   }
   ```
3. From within `link` specifying both `preLink` and `postLink` explicitly:

   ```
   link: {
     pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... },
     post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
   }
   ```
4. From withing `link` using `postLink` implicitly:

   ```
   link: function postLink( ... ) { ... }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can provide your own pre and post link functions. See the directive blueprint at [Angular Docs' Comprehensive Directive API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile).

```
{
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
        return {
            pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... },
            post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
        }
        // or
        // return function postLink( ... ) { ... }
    },
}
```