# angularjs $rootscope event does not fire on parent directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two directive on my design.

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.directive("dirContainer", function($rootScope){
      return {
       template: "<div><clock></clock></div>",
       link:function(scope){        
        $rootScope.$on("onClockCreated",function(){
                alert(1)
        })
      }
    }
});

app.directive("clock", function($rootScope){
      return {
       template: "<div>clock</div>",
       link:function(scope){
            var clock = { time: "10:12" };

          $rootScope.$broadcast("onClockCreated",clock);
      }
    }
});
```

I want to get `clock` directive created event with `$rootScope` broadcast. But container directive does not populate the alert.

This is [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/aaojsLgn/) of application.

**UPDATE:**

I have added scope.$emit and it populated alert.

```
app.directive("dirContainer", function($rootScope){
        return {
        template: "<div><clock></clock></div>",
      compile:function(scope){          
        $rootScope.$on("onClockCreated",function(){
                alert(1)
        })

        $scope.$emit("onClockCreated",function(){
                alert(1)
        })
      }
    }
});
```

But I could not understand. How it wroks?

Comment: Your $scopes are arranged in a hierarchy.  $emit will send the event message up the hierarchy and $broadcast will send the message down the hierarchy.  $rootScope is at the top of the hierarchy.  I'm not a huge fan of this approach if it's not needed.  For instance how are you going to unit test it?  Is it a unit test at that point?  My solution below resolves all your issues while maintaining modularity.

Answer (score 1):

You have got a timing problem here. The link function of the clock directive is called before the link function of your dirContainer directive.
You can see it, if you put a console.log in each link function.
So your event is emitted before the dirContainer directive is listening.
If you could tell us what you are trying to achieve, we maybe could suggest you an appropriate solution.

Comment: I have a general component  that I can put it any dom element or any directive. But sometimes I neet to access clock object from parent elements that its container.

Comment: ok. So you should think about using the solution from DilumN or put your clock-Object into a service so every component who needs the object can get it from the service.

Comment: Can I solve this timing problem with $q defer? If yes how?

Answer (score 1):

Just change `link` to `compile`

```
compile:function(scope){        
            $rootScope.$on("onClockCreated",function(){
                    alert(1)
            })
          }
```

here is demo https://jsfiddle.net/avsubL66/

Comment: why use compile function? @nabica says that this is a timing problem. Does compile solves this timing problrm?

Comment: compile is fired when all the child directives are rendered so it solves your problem

Comment: here is how are these link and compile functions defined http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105336/can-angularjs-directive-pre-link-and-post-link-functions-be-customized

Comment: I read about compile, but compile does not has a scope. It has element and attribute parameters.

Answer (score 1):

### You can even do this in way by creating parent child directive manner

```
 <div ng-app="myapp">
<container>
  <clock></clock>
  </container>
   </div>
var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);


app.directive("container", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    controller: function () {
      this.clockcreated = function (message) { 
        alert("It says: " + message);
      };
    }
  };
});


app.directive("clock", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    require: "^container",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, containerCtrl) {
      containerCtrl.clockcreated("Clock created");
    }
  };
});
```

Working link - https://jsfiddle.net/2nqhsvmp/1/

Comment: I will use clock directive in multiple dom elements. I used it in `container` directive in this stuation. Later I will use it in `leftPanel` or in `rightPanel` directive

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to expose an api for your parent controller.

Working fork of your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/auqwkbsg/).

This resolves your concerns with race conditions.

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.directive("dirContainer", function($rootScope){
    return {
    template: "<div><clock></clock></div>",
    controller: ['$scope', function DirContainerController($scope) {
        this.sendAlert = function() {
            alert(1);
        };
    }],
    }
});

app.directive("clock", function($timeout, $rootScope){
    return {
    require: '^^dirContainer',
    template: "<div>clock</div>",
    link:function(scope, element, attrs, dirCtrl){
        var clock = { time: "10:12" };
            dirCtrl.sendAlert();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution,

your `dirContrainer` directive should listen to the broadcast on his `scope`. Not his `rootScope`.

```
app.directive("dirContainer", function($rootScope){
        return {
        template: "<div><clock></clock></div>",
      link:function(scope){         
        scope.$on("onClockCreated",function(clock){
                alert(1)
        })
      }
    }
});
```

And also make sure to put a `$timeout` when you are doing this testing because `broadcast.$on` is not ready when you `$broadcast` from the `clock` directive.

```
app.directive("clock", function($rootScope, $timeout){
        return {
        template: "<div>clock</div>",
      link:function(scope){
            var clock = { time: "10:12" };

          $timeout(function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast("onClockCreated",clock);
          });

      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Timeout set 2000. But dirContainer creation may take 3000 ms. Is there ansured solution about these stuations.

Comment: You don't have to worry about the number. Just remove 2000 & it will work fine as well. I edited the answer. From $timeout, the broadcast will happen in the next execution cycle. So by that time $on is ready to execute

Comment: is it possible to use $q defer?

Comment: No you can't replance $timeout by $q